# SQL View MAX(date) craziness

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a previously created SQL view that contains the data I am looking to get. It has Case when's and it is making it confusing for me to run MAX(date)... I have tried to run a view based on it and it just keeps timing out... I can create a new view with the data I need but I still need the data manipulated and must leave in some of these Case when's...

This view currently produces this info

```
THDATE              ComponentItemNumber Issued Quantity
12/23/2013 12:00:00 AM  TTMS-12.7-9 19
12/23/2013 12:00:00 AM  TTMS-4.8-9  8.34
12/23/2013 12:00:00 AM  TTMS-4.8-9  10.66
12/23/2013 12:00:00 AM  44476-3112  2
12/23/2013 12:00:00 AM  M80-0130005 NULL
```

What I want to do is simply Get the Max date for each item#
here is the current view... Can someone help me with creating a SQL Statement that does this? Please... I am using SQL 2000

```
SELECT  THDATE
      , CASE WHEN dbo.udf_GetHistoryChar(THBODY + THBODY2 + THBODY3 + THBODY4,
                                         7) = 'C' THEN NULL
             ELSE dbo.udf_GetHistoryVarchar(THBODY + THBODY2 + THBODY3
                                            + THBODY4, 10)
        END AS ComponentItemNumber
      , CASE WHEN dbo.udf_GetHistoryChar(THBODY + THBODY2 + THBODY3 + THBODY4,
                                         3) = 'C' THEN NULL
             WHEN dbo.udf_GetHistoryChar(THBODY + THBODY2 + THBODY3 + THBODY4,
                                         2) = 'D' THEN NULL
             ELSE dbo.udf_GetHistoryFloat(THBODY + THBODY2 + THBODY3 + THBODY4,
                                          17)
        END AS IssuedQuantity
FROM    dbo.Mfg_TRANHIS AS T1
WHERE   ( THTRID = 'PICK' )
        AND ( THFLAG = '1' )
        AND ( dbo.udf_GetHistoryChar(THBODY + THBODY2 + THBODY3 + THBODY4, 1) = 'C' )
        AND ( NOT ( ( CASE WHEN dbo.udf_GetHistoryChar(THBODY + THBODY2
                                                       + THBODY3 + THBODY4, 7) = 'C'
                           THEN NULL
                           ELSE dbo.udf_GetHistoryVarchar(THBODY + THBODY2
                                                          + THBODY3 + THBODY4,
                                                          10)
                      END ) LIKE 'CU%' )
            )
        AND ( NOT ( ( CASE WHEN dbo.udf_GetHistoryChar(THBODY + THBODY2
                                                       + THBODY3 + THBODY4, 2) LIKE '[MP]'
                           THEN dbo.udf_GetHistoryVarchar(THBODY + THBODY2
                                                          + THBODY3 + THBODY4,
                                                          4)
                           WHEN dbo.udf_GetHistoryChar(THBODY + THBODY2
                                                       + THBODY3 + THBODY4, 3) = 'C'
                           THEN dbo.udf_GetHistoryVarchar(THBODY + THBODY2
                                                          + THBODY3 + THBODY4,
                                                          5)
                           WHEN dbo.udf_GetHistoryChar(THBODY + THBODY2
                                                       + THBODY3 + THBODY4, 2) = 'D'
                           THEN dbo.udf_GetHistoryVarchar(THBODY + THBODY2
                                                          + THBODY3 + THBODY4,
                                                          5)
                           WHEN dbo.udf_GetHistoryChar(THBODY + THBODY2
                                                       + THBODY3 + THBODY4, 7) = 'C'
                           THEN dbo.udf_GetHistoryVarchar(THBODY + THBODY2
                                                          + THBODY3 + THBODY4,
                                                          4)
                           ELSE dbo.udf_GetHistoryVarchar(THBODY + THBODY2
                                                          + THBODY3 + THBODY4,
                                                          4)
                      END ) LIKE 'VM%' )
            )
```

Comment: Please format your question properly and reduce it to the very problem.

Comment: all those udf's, CASE statements, and NOT's?  You probably should patch the leaks (i.e., fix your data model) before trying to bail water.

Comment: Scalar-valued functions are notoriously slow in SQL Server. It's not as pretty, but using table-valued functions can help improve performance immensely.

Comment: Your query pretty much made my head explode, but I don't see any columns in there where the name indicates anything like a date, nor do I see a `MAX` anywhere.

Comment: @Andrew First column referenced: `THDATE`, but no `MAX()`

Comment: So this is inherited... I am careful with it because I do not know what it affects within our ERP and this was a built in view... I don't even know where to begin... sigh

Comment: My head busted a week ago looking at it... This is simplified... I want top use the MAX function on the THDATE field but it times out ... I am sure because of inefficiency but I don't know how to get around it....

Comment: It was much more complex... lol

Comment: I hope that ERP vendor went out of business...  does it have to be a view to fetch the max date, or can you use a proc?  And, does this underlying view perform adequately well?

Comment: Terrible... I tried to suck the data into a crystal report to manipulate it but it just limits my ability so bad and it takes 15 minutes to run....

Comment: I am accessing the data in Crystal Reports so it needs to be a view or a table

Comment: You are doing the same code over and over again.  You should refactor to only do it once.
You are doing the same code over and over again.  You should refactor to only do it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are asking how to get past the Timeout issue.

I have experienced this in the past and *so far* the best solution I have come up with is to push the data into a table based on the starting view.  Then create the second view based on that table.  However this required that I have a set time (in some cases every 30 minutes) that a stored procedure would do this for me and that may not work for you.

Some other things that I found worked were to limit the amount of data I was working with before doing the formatting.  Also making sure you have proper keys/indexes on the table(s) you are working with.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing... I went in to create a procedure but I haven't got that nailed out yet.. thanks